# Showing wrong axis in 2D array when value is out of range

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing, numpy-indexing

I have a 2D array (row*column)row means axis0 and column mean aixs1.

example:

```
a=np.array([[10,20,30],[40,50,60]])
```

now when I am trying to access the value(out of range along axis 0)I am getting below Exception which is correct.

```
print(a[-3][-1])

    IndexError: index -3 is out of bounds for `axis 0` with size 2
```

Note: Same when I am trying along the axis1 It is still showing same **axis0** which should be **axis1**.

```
print(a[-2][5])
IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because you first subset `a` to a vector, which is 1 dimensional.

```
>>> a[-2]
array([10, 20, 30])

>>> np.array([10, 20, 30])[5]
IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3
```

However if you slice both dimension at once, you get the expected error:

```
>>> a[-2, 5]
IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 3
```